# Can you reverse a PyTorch neural network and activate the inputs from the outputs?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Can we activate the outputs of a NN to gain insight into how the neurons are connected to input features?

If I take a basic NN example from the PyTorch tutorials. Here is an example of a `f(x,y)` training example.

```py
import torch

N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

x = torch.randn(N, D_in)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
)

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

learning_rate = 1e-4
for t in range(500):
    y_pred = model(x)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in model.parameters():
            param -= learning_rate * param.grad
```

After I've finished training the network to predict `y` from `x` inputs. Is it possible to reverse the trained NN so that it can now predict `x` from `y` inputs?

I don't expect `y` to match the original *inputs* that trained the `y` outputs. So I expect to see what *features* the model activates on to match `x` and `y`.

If it is possible, then how do I rearrange the `Sequential` model without breaking all the weights and connections?

Comment: It's definitely possible by creating two separate `Sequential` networks that share their layers in reverse order. Though this only reverses the order of layers, not the order of computational steps (since each layers performs `activation(W*x + b)`). But for that to be meaningful you'd need to be able to reverse the `activation` function which in your example, using `ReLu`, is not possible since it doesn't have an inverse on `(-inf, inf)`. So you need to be more precise what you actually mean by saying "reverse a neural network".

Comment: Are you looking for [feature visualization](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/)?

Comment: @Shai that is very cool, but I'm just looking to reverse a NN at this stage of my learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible but only for very special cases. For a feed-forward network (`Sequential`) each of the layers needs to be reversible; that means the following arguments apply to each layer separately. The transformation associated with one layer is `y = activation(W*x + b)` where `W` is the weight matrix and `b` the bias vector. In order to solve for `x` we need to perform the following steps:

1. Reverse `activation`; not all activation functions have an inverse though. For example the `ReLU` function does not have an inverse on `(-inf, 0)`. If we used `tanh` on the other hand we can use its inverse which is `0.5 * log((1 + x) / (1 - x))`.
2. Solve `W*x = inverse_activation(y) - b` for `x`; for a unique solution to exist `W` must have similar row and column rank and `det(W)` must be non-zero. We can control the former by choosing a specific network architecture while the latter depends on the training process.

So for a neural network to be reversible it must have a very specific architecture: all layers must have the same number of input and output neurons (i.e. square weight matrices) and the activation functions all need to be invertible.

**Code:** Using PyTorch we will have to do the inversion of the network manually, both in terms of solving the system of linear equations as well as finding the inverse activation function. Consider the following example of a 1-layer neural network (since the steps apply to each layer separately extending this to more than 1 layer is trivial):

```
import torch

N = 10  # number of samples
n = 3   # number of neurons per layer

x = torch.randn(N, n)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(n, n), torch.nn.Tanh()
)

y = model(x)

z = y  # use 'z' for the reverse result, start with the model's output 'y'.
for step in list(model.children())[::-1]:
    if isinstance(step, torch.nn.Linear):
        z = z - step.bias[None, ...]
        z = z[..., None]  # 'torch.solve' requires N column vectors (i.e. shape (N, n, 1)).
        z = torch.solve(z, step.weight)[0]
        z = torch.squeeze(z)  # remove the extra dimension that we've added for 'torch.solve'.
    elif isinstance(step, torch.nn.Tanh):
        z = 0.5 * torch.log((1 + z) / (1 - z))

print('Agreement between x and z: ', torch.dist(x, z))
```

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood correctly, there are two questions here:

1. Is it possible to determine what features in the input have activated neurons?
2. If so, is it possible to use this information to generate samples from `p(x|y)`?

Regarding `1`, a basic way to determine if a neuron is sensitive to an input feature `x_i` is to compute the gradient of this neuron's output w.r.t `x_i`. A high gradient will indicate sensitivity to a particular input element. There is a rich literature on the subject, for example, you can have a look at guided backpropagation or at [GradCam](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391) (the latter is about classification with convnets, but it does contain useful ideas).

As for `2`, I don't think that your approach to "reversing the problem" is correct. The problem is that your network is discriminative and what it outputs can be seen as `argmax_y p(y|x)`. Note that this is a point-wise estimation, not a full modeling of the distribution. However, the inverse problem that you're interested in seems to be sampling from

```
p(x|y)=constant*p(y|x)p(x).
```

You don't know how to sample from `p(y|x)` and you don't know anything about `p(x)`. Even if you use a method to discover correlations between the neurons and specific input features, you have only discovered which features where more important to the networks prediction, but depending on the nature of `y` this might be insufficiant. Consider a toy example where your inputs `x` are 2d points distributed according to some distribution in `R^2` and where the output `y` is binary, such that any `(a,b) in R^2` is classified as `1` if `a<1` and it is classified as `0` if `a>1`. Then a discriminative network could learn the vertical line `x=1` as its decision boundary. Inspecting correlations between neurons and input features will reveal that only the first coordinate was useful in this prediction, but this information is not sufficient for sampling from the full 2d distribution of inputs.

I think that [Variational autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder#Variational_autoencoder_(VAE)) could be what you're looking for.